# create a new copy of local git repo

Tags: git, github, init

I am working on a Java web project where I m responsible for the web content. The other developers are not interested in using git, but that is another story. So I created a repo for the WebContent folder.  But recently there were so many changes to the java src files that I decided to do a wholesale delete and replacement of the entire project on my test server, only to realize too late that I deleted things like .git, and ignore.  So my question is what should I do? Do I do a pull? Do I just git init again, add everything and commit? Tganks for any insight.

Comment: Clone again from the remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deleted everything, then you just have to `clone` again and recreate your work and `.gitignore`.

If it was **really** important stuff that you **could not** replace, you could attempt to file carve (recover deleted files from the File System) against the device.

For instance tools like `extundelete` (http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) allow you to do this (assuming and `ext` based File System), but there is no guarantee that it will work.

It is probably better just to recreate the data.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I actually have all of the files in the directory except .git and .gitignore. I want the diretory to once again be a git repo.  Is your answer the same?

Comment: It is. The `.git` file holds *all* the git data, so you can only recreate that by cloning a valid repo again. If you do `git init` you will create a new *completely different* git repo that has no shared history with your project. You could, in principle, link that to your upstream repo again, but that is a lot of work you don't need to do since the same thing can be accomplished using `git clone`.